# CSS and JS Not working properly after adding Extension

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, javascript, css

Hello guys i am new to Magento so please help with this ,

i added a MarketPlace extension by Cybage, extension works fine, but the Problem is that Theme that i was using (RWD Theme) has got affected i tried to make some changes in css but it Doesn't work , later i uninstalled the extension and found that CSS and javaScirpt works fine now , So every time i install this extension the CSS and JavaScript of the magento website get affected ,  this extension add few things of its own to the page and doesn't allow to edit the CSS or JS ,

what should i do so that extension doesn't have any effect on my default CSS and JS  ?

Comment: Hi Suraj and welcome to MageOverflow. Unfortunately we are not supporting third party themes/extensions. Beside this you are providing too less informations. Please edit your questions, add what you have changed and where you expect it to show up, then maybe someone can help.